# What is a "Gather" service for?

Tags: submitting-work

There is this [Gather](http://www.gather.com/) service in the webz. It's been said that this service is for writers. How exactly can it help me as a writer? Cause I didn't get anything meaningful from their ["about"](http://www.gather.com/about.jsp) page, and I want to gather knowledge from people who've used it.

Comment: IMHO this is off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went to their about page, and that pointed to [socialwrite.gather.com](http://socialwrite.gather.com), which says:

> #### Payment
>
> Socialwriters are paid in the following ways:
>
> ***Per Article***: $2.50-$10 for any articles posted on Gather that receive a minimum of 250 unique page views
>
> AND
>
> ***Monthly Bonus***: $25-$100 based on the popularity of their writing throughout the month
>
> #### Socialwriter Requirements
>
> Socialwriters must be U.S. residents… Gather recommends Socialwriters write 20 posts per month so they can actively learn the content guidelines and sharpen their writing skills for search engine pick-up. Seventy-five percent of their posts should cover topics in their assigned writing category, twenty-five percent of posts can be in other categories.

Sounds like their writers are supposed to generate SEO-friendly copy <sup><sub>(pfui)</sub></sup> and in return Gather *may* pay them. Or maybe not. Depends on how honest their bookkeeping is, and I doubt their contracts include letting writers audit their books.

Given that they don't pay a penny until/unless you break that 250 page view mark, I recommend blogging for yourself instead.

Comment: So it's just the money. I thought they can help me progress.

Comment: @Daniel - from the sound of things, no—they just dump your content on the Web, after which you have to hope that people show up to read.

Comment: Looks like a lot of work for less than US minimum wage.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see it's a bit like Suite 101. The site asks you to write short topical pieces that orient to good SEO results and garnishes your article pages with ads. You get a cut of the click-through revenue.

I may be wrong.