# Anybody know anything about examiner.com?

Tags: publishing

Apparently it's some sort of "pro-am" site.  I applied to be a travel writer and they, uh, picked me.  I'm curious if anybody knows where examiner.com is on a 1 to 10 scale where "1" is "Application process?  *Everybody* gets in, they're just scamming you for free content" and "10" is "ZOMG!  You're writing for examiner.com?  Wow, can I touch you..."

Comment: A similar (but not identical) question: [What is a "Gather" service for?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/669/what-is-a-gather-service-for/)

Answer (score 8):

1 is correct.

See [this overview on Examiner.com](http://www.writersweekly.com/the_latest_from_angelahoycom/005351_05062009.html), and [individual user experiences](http://www.writersweekly.com/the_latest_from_angelahoycom/005364_05132009.html). It's a pay-per-click site - it's not going to earn you fame, fortune, or even a respectable line for your CV. If you want to write such content anyway, then the platform and pocket money might be nice; if you think you can leverage or promote your writing into some sort of success elsewhere, I suppose that's about as feasible as doing so on Blogger.

But you're asking about prestige of the venue, selectivity, about inherent career potential? They have none.

There are some more in-depth considerations of the [cons](http://accrispin.blogspot.com/2010/03/guest-blog-post-content-mills-why.html) and [pros](http://accrispin.blogspot.com/2010/03/guest-blog-post-content-mills-just.html) of content mills at Writer Beware:

Comment: Sad panda is sad.

Comment: Its nice to know not only of this company, but this type of scam in general.

Comment: @Shan: I just added a couple of links with more on the subject. More of a scheme than a scam, but far from being in most writers' best interests.

Comment: While I agree with the general evaluation, characterizing it as a scam seems unfair.  You don't get fame or fortune, but you're never offered it, either.  They do exactly what they say they do for writers... that not being spectacular doesn't make it a scam.